# String to Bytes, trying to open an csv file with a list. PYTHON

Tags: excel, python-3.x, byte

```
import csv

date = []

open_price = []

high = []

low = []

close = []

volume = []

adj_close = []


with open(r'C:\Users\bruno.rojas\Desktop\Python_Data\SPX_Prices.csv') as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        date.append(row[0])
        open_price.append(row[1])
        high.append(row[2])
        low.append(row[3])
        close.append(row[4])
        volume.append(row[5])
        adj_close.append(row[6])
date = str(date).encode()
open_price = open_price
open_prices = dict(zip(date, open_price))
high_prices = dict(zip(date, high))
low_prices = dict(zip(date, low))

close_prices = dict(zip(date,close))
volume_prices = dict(zip(date, volume))
adj_close_prices = dict(zip(date, adj_close))
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(date)
```

I am trying to ultimately send each dictionary to its own excel sheet but I am running into the problem of not being able to transform my list into a byte style object despite using the .encode function
I am only trying to output a list in this example.
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: If you are on python-3, don't use `'wb'`, use `'w'` with the `csv` module. Then, just use the regular string, without `encode`. I have no idea what's going on. Maybe the problem is the `csv` module is turning your bytes objects into strings under the hood.

Comment: This fixed my problem, thanks a ton. Might you have any idea where the excel file executed to?

Comment: You are making a `csv`, which is a plain-text file. It isn't an excel file, per se, but excel understands `csv` files well. It is saved wherever your working directory is, because you used `open('output.csv')` to open the file, so it will use the local directory. If you want to save it somewhere specific, use a full path, e.g. `'C:\Users\bruno.rojas\Desktop\Python_Data\output.csv'`

Comment: If you want to check which directory you wrote to, try adding  `import os; print('inside', os.getcwd())` to your script

Comment: I was able to change the file location to a specific one which I found. Thank you!